# How to check if input is already entered before in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I want to generate QR code for given input,and I have done it. But I want to set Error if QR code for given input is already generate before. Here is my code.

**`Forms.py`**

```
from django import forms
from generateqr.models import *
import qrcode
class Qrgenerate(forms.Form):
input =forms.CharField()

def clean_input(self):
  valinput=self.cleaned_data['input']
  if len(valinput)<5:
          raise forms.ValidationError('Enter more than 5 ')
  else:

     img=qrcode.make(valinput)
     img.save("test.png")
  return  valinput
```

**`views.py`**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Qrgenerate
import qrcode
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def showformdata(request):

if request.method =='POST':
    fm = Qrgenerate(request.POST or None)
 
   
return render(request,"home.html",{'form':fm })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDigT.png

This is form where I want to set error if input is already entered by user before. I have tried with this code, but not worked and gives `ERROR Attribute 'object' is not found`.

```
  def clean_input(self):
    valinput = self.cleaned_data['username']

    try:
        input = Qrcode.objects.get(input==input)
    except input.DoesNotExist:
        return input
    raise forms.ValidationError(i'input "%s" is already in use.' % input)
```

models.py

```
enter code here
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class Qr(models.Model):
input = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

updated forms.py

```
from django import forms
from generateqr.models import *
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import qrcode
class Qrgenerate(forms.Form):
input=forms.CharField()
# img=forms.ImageField()
def clean_input(self):
  input=self.cleaned_data['input']
  try:
     Qr.objects.get(input__iexact=input)
   
  except Qr.DoesNotExist:
     
     img=qrcode.make(input)
     img.save("test.png")
     
  raise forms.ValidationError('input "%s" is already in use.' %input)
```

Thanks in advance.Please help me out.

Comment: You used `==` in your `get(input==input)` method instead of `=`.

Comment: qrcode library's `img.save("test.png")` will save to a file on the local disk. `Qrcode.objects.get(input==input)` will look into the django database in the `qrcode` table for a matching input. how is this supposed to find a match? and you're trying to check for a user.DoesNotExist, when there's no user involved (which, probably should, but that's a different story)

Comment: @LotB I have used input instead of user..still not work

Comment: 1: do not edit the original code posted. 2: you want to check on the `Qrcode.DoesNotExist`. But first you want to save something on the db.

Comment: @LotB How to save in db?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

Comment: @LotB I have tried with this documentation ,included models.py and update forms.py but   it gives error when input is not taken. Please help.

Comment: You're testing if a QR code exists (for the given input) in the database, but you never save the one you newly created to the database. So the test will always yield false for database existence.

Comment: Using `input` as a variable name shadows the built-in `input()` function, which tends to be a bad idea (can cause confusion at least). Also, please fix your indentation: it's all over the place, and lacking in large parts of the code.

Comment: @9769953  So how to save input in database ?in views.py or forms.py?I can use forms.save()??I need little more explanation ,please help .